# Is it appropriate to use Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, caching

Working on a legacy ASP.NET application we've found that ASP.NET session gets used for caching some objects, but for some objects `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching` gets used.

Is there any reason to use `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching` over standard ASP.NET Session?

### Edit

In my scenario, the Enterprise Library caching is actually being used to cache per-user data by appending the ASP.NET Session ID to the cached item's key.

Comment: Do you mean standard ASP.NET Session or standard ASP.NET Cache? as session and cache are for two different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session and Cache are different concepts.

If you want to share the object between all users of your site you should use Cache while Session is for storing user specific data.

So your question should not be:

> Is there any reason to use
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching
>   over standard ASP.NET Session?

but:

> Is there any reason to use
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching
>   over standard ASP.NET Cache?

and the answer to this question as always is: it depends on your scenario. [This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/leon.pereira/elcachingapplblock07142005063621am/elcachingapplblock.aspx) provides an overview of where can the Caching Application Block be used and what issues does it try to resolve.

Comment: If the question is the latter, one reason to use the caching application block is if you share assemblies (that require caching) between web apps and windows apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... Session is mainly for user specific data storage in the application and cache can be used for both user specific and application specific data storages.